# Find missing points

Tags: guild-wars-2

I'm missing only one point of interest in a map.

I went over and over the map, can't find the damn point.

Is there some way to quickly find missing points on the maps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I usually do is compare the state of my own map against the maps shown [here](http://gw2.mmorpg-life.com/interactive-maps/).

The great thing about the maps on that website is that is shows screenshots on how to actually get to the particular point, very useful for tricky vistas.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not.

The best way is to get a list of all the points of interest in a zone (for instance, 
[Mount Maelstrom](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mount_Maelstrom)
)

And compare your own map to the list, checking each point off in turn.